# Dynamic Field in Lightning web component salesforce

Tags: salesforce, lwc

We need to create a lightning web component where we would input the following fields of the Case Object (These fields would be dynamic. Can be changed without changing any code. Make all fields required):

Account
Contact
Type
Case Reason
Product
Subject
Description
And there would be two buttons Submit Case and Cancel. When user clicks on the Submit button the system would create a case in Salesforce with the values defined in the input.

Comment: What have you tried, what are you stuck on?

Comment: How to make it dynamic using custom metadata type

Comment: We're not a free coding service, especially since this looks like an interview type of question. Post the code you've written so far